# Эмуляция клика OS X

Tags: macos

Можно ли эмулировать клик левой кнопкой мыши циклически, с определенным промежутком по времени?

OS: OS 10.11.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369340/how-to-make-a-click-with-a-mouse-to-a-specific-position-on-a-mac